# confused in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory for uploaded photos, sorted with date, like this:

```
http://example.com/uploads/2012-12-08/abcd.png
```

and I created an `index.php` inside my `/uploads/` folder with a `.htaccess`

I could use the `index.php` to control the image `width` and `height`.

the original url looks like this: `http://example.com/uploads/?url=2012-12-08/abcd.png&width=128`.

Here's the `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /uploads/index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And if I enter the URL: `http://example.com/uploads/2012-12-08/abcd.png&width=128` will appear the resized image

but the issue is the browser display the image extension as `png&width=128`

also the image URL cannot be shown in some forums, because the `&` symbol.

how can I change the `.png&width=128` into `.png?width=128`?

I have tried many rules but none work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /uploads/index.php?url=$1&%1 [QSA]
```

Comment: but there're more that two query string,maximum : ?url=$&width=$&height=$&rotate=$&filter=$&

Comment: I tested it here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be and it works! So, if it isn't working, paste your full `.htaccess` file content

Comment: but I entered .jpg?width=256 the width didn't  change,my htaccess file same as yours,just add rewriteengine on in the first line,my htaccess inside the uploads folder,also had one in the parent folder

Comment: [Sun Dec 09 03:48:34 2012] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
'

Comment: yea I get the log,see the reply upside

Comment: replace that line with: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, so remove `[NC]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with URL Friendly:

```
http://mysite.com/uploads/2012-12-08/abcd.png/128
```

Info: http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

I hope it helps somewhat.

Regards.